# Fluid simulation pours into the cup in a box shape and won't spill

Tags: fluid-simulation

I was working with the fluid simulator in Blender, and I wanted to make an animation where water flows into a cup and spills out. When I bake the fluid it pours into the cup in a box shape, even if the bounds are the same shape of the cup. The other problem is that the fluid won't spill out when the cup is knocked over.

Is there a way to fix either of these problems?

Comment: The [fluid domain object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/domain.html) will be always treated as a box so don't edit it. Instead add Fluid modifier to cup and set it to Obstacle.Same for your second problem; fluid can't be anywhere except for the inside of domain.

Answer (score 1):

Setting your cup to obstacle (as mentioned in the comment above) should fix the problem of the cup bounds being square. The main thing you would want to fix, though, would be the size of your fluid domain. It will not affect the fluid, but will simulate the bounds of where the fluid will go. A smaller domain will give the waters smaller boundaries. Also, if you are using a rigid body for the cup, it will not simulate well with the fluid.